# Able to make a VPN connection from client to the tunnel_server (using apple's SimpleTunnel app) but unable to browse the internet on the device

Tags: ios, macos, vpn, nat, portforwarding

I built the SimpleTunnel sample app (provided by apple) and am running the VPN client on a IOS device and the VPN server (tunnel_server) on a MAC running OS 10.11 (OS X El Capitan)

**On MAC :-**

```
$ sudo ./tunnel_server 550 ../../tunnel_server/config.plist
```

Response :-

```
tunnel_server[87725:2604682] Starting network service on port 550

tunnel_server[87725:2604682] Network service published successfully
```

**On IOS device :-**

Next I ran the PacketTunnel app on my IOS device. Added a VPN configuration with the correct IP address (the IP address of the MAC running the tunnel_server) and the port number (port number for the tunnel_server which is 550).

Next I try to connect to the VPN from the `IO` device and this seems to go through fine as I see the VPN sign in status bar.

Response on the screen running tunnel_server :-

```
tunnel_server[87739:2606312] Accepted a new connection

tunnel_server[87739:2606312] Allocated address Optional("10.8.0.15")
```

However I am not able to browse the internet using Safari on the IOS device (it times out), but am able to do the same from the MAC.

Any insights on what I might be missing ?

Please note that my MAC doesn't have OS X server installed. Also I did run the following two comands from a terminal before starting the tunnel_server on the MAC

```
sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1

sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.fw.enable=1
```

Comment: Hi, I am also trying to get this to work but I can't even get pass the connection part. Which I suspect is a new issue introduced by macOS Sierra because the "sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.fw.enable=1" no longer works. Anyway, I think the official answer to your query can be found here --> https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/69962
Basically Apple doesn't support off mac routing...